# Options for line output doubling as headphone output

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, amplifier, audio, headphones

As the title says, I'd like a combined line/headphone audio output with the following design criteria:

1. ideally driven from 5V single supply (12V available, but noisy)
2. flat frequency response, also in the bass spectrum
3. avoid electrolytic caps if possible due to size constraints
4. minimal current draw while connected to line input (instead of headphones)
5. SMD components only

The options I see are:

1. power amp chip with ground-referenced output (LM386, LM4871, MC34119)
2. power amp chip with differential output (e.g. LM4871)
3. parallel regular opamps (e.g. all 4 units of an MCP6004 driving the same output through 100 ohm resistors)

Regarding option 1, a large AC coupling cap is needed in order to maintain adequate bass levels. In my tests, around 1000 µF or more do the trick, but of course this means electrolytic caps. Also, these circuits have a low value resistor to ground, which means unnecessarily high current draw while driving a line input.

Option 2 is attractive because it eliminates the need for a large coupling cap (as well as large decoupling caps), but if this is going to be used as a line output, I couldn't connect the sleeve contact of the output socket to one of the differential outputs, otherwise it will be shorted to ground by the next device in line. I could, as I understand it, connect either of the differential outputs to the tip/ring contact, and the sleeve to ground, but this configuration then needs a similar cap/resistor combo as option 1, right?

Option 3 has actually performed best in my tests, but I still have the same output capacitor problem. I'm not a fan of adding a negative supply via a voltage inverter chip, but as far as I see it, this would allow me to use a dual supply opamp and I wouldn't need an output coupling cap at all.

Any thoughts on this situation? Anything I may be missing?

Comment: Some thoughts: inexpensive 1000uF 6.3V SMT aluminum electrolytics are available. If your line output is going into a true balanced line input then it is OK to have a DC bias on tip and ring as the receiver will subtract out the DC. Can you perhaps consider separate jacks for line out and headphone? That would simplify things - line out could use a smaller cap (if unbalanced drive needed), headphone shield could be connected to 2.5V bias point.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of this type of cap, but there are space restrictions on the PCB, or rather above it, and even the shortest of those will not fit, so I would prefer to be able to stick with ceramics. Maybe tantalum ones are an option, never used them, and apparently they do like to explode? Good point about the balanced inputs, but the line output would go to an unbalanced input usually. Separate jacks would not really work due to space constraints. :/

Comment: What are the signal source details?

Comment: It's just an audio signal, maybe 2V peak-to-peak, coming from an op-amp buffer.

Comment: Have you searched for single supply headphone driver ICs? They may generate a negative supply for you. Also, what are your specs for the amplifier, like frequency range or impedance of load?

Comment: That's a good idea, I didn't know something like that existed. Looking at the TI/AD websites now. Frequency range is 20-20k Hz, impedance should be such that it works up to normal volume levels for any common type of headphone, so I guess no less than 32 ohms?

Comment: @Justme Looking at the datasheets, the TPA6132 or MAX97220 are perfect fits. I ordered some samples and will give them a try. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a type of chips called headphone amplifiers.

Some of them work from single supply and can generate a negative supply for DC coupled output.

They are available from multiple manufacturers.

Comment: As I said above, I'll be testing the TPA6132 or MAX97220, either of which according to the datasheets should solve my problem perfectly. Thanks a ton!